# Apache Camel to handle encoding declared in XML-File

Tags: java, xml-parsing, apache-camel, xml-encoding

I'm trying to parse an UTF-16 encoded document using Apache Camel Splitter with xtokenize, this delegates to Woodstox (com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader), also I cannot know the encoding of a file before I read it, currently some files are UTF-16, others UTF-8:

```
.split().xtokenize(getToken(), 'w', NAMESPACES)
```

The problem I encounter is that Camel tells Woodstox which encoding to use:

```
String charset = IOHelper.getCharsetName(exchange);
```

It sets the default UTF-8 as encoding, so BasicStreamReader tries to read BOM bytes as UTF-8 and fails with

```
com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '�' (code 65533 / 0xfffd) in prolog; expected '<'
```

As specified in https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-guessing XML Parser (Woodstox) should be able to autodetect the file encoding if only Camel lets it do the work.

Is there a way not to implement the encoding detection myself?

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: 2.17.5 forgot to mention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a Camel JIRA ticket:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11846
From my comments you can see there is no easy solution for splitting UTF-16 XML with Camel without knowing it's UTF-16 in advance.

Though subclassing XMLTokenExpressionIterator, which is an ExpressionAdapter and switching to InputStream works in the first place, there are several other places with xslt & xpath & conversion to StaxSource where it will break for the same reason.

As a workaround I consider it's easier to let XmlStreamReader find out encoding in advance (happens at the initialization) and setting Exchange.CHARSET_NAME header or property.

Comment: I commented referenced JIRA ticket with my workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I can see the current source code will fallback and use the platform encoding. So your use-case with the encoding provided in the XML stanza is not supported.

I am not sure if Camel really need to fallback to a default platform encoding as it uses the `java.util.Scanner` in the splitter, and it supports scanning without using a specific encoding.

Maybe you can try to patch the source code in the `XMLTokenExpressionIterator` and test it locally for you, and report back here.

We can then likely take a look at make it optional in Apache Camel to use the fallback encoding or not.

And in your current version of Apache Camel you can always extend `XMLTokenExpressionIterator` and override the `doEvaluate` method and then call the `createIterator` method without a charset parameter. And then use your custom iterator with the Camel splitter.

Comment: the fallback is not platform encoding: it's: 
String DEFAULT_CHARSET_PROPERTY  = "org.apache.camel.default.charset"; when defined, otherwise UTF-8, so it's UTF-8  by default. But this is better than relying on "random" platform encoding

Comment: I could pinpoint the issue: Camel's XmlTokenExpressionIterator uses a Reader (RecordableReader), thus saying it knows the charset of the input. So Woodstox (for example) would use ReaderBootstrapper as opposed to StreamBootstrapper. See javadoc of ReaderBootstrapper:
`Input bootstrap class used when input comes from a Reader; in this case, encoding is already known, and thus encoding from XML declaration (if any) is only double-checked, not really used.` StreamBootstrapper is able to recognize declared encoding.

Comment: I've patched `XMLTokenExpressionIterator` easily replacing `RecordableReader` with `RecordableInputStream` from the same package. createXMLStreamReader(in) is deprecated, the other method wants to have the exchange to choose a charset, but you can fix it easily. Now it fails in the next step inside XmlConverter, where I apply xslt to extracted string for the same reason: `XMLStreamReader r = new StaxConverter().createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(source))` It does not know it's UTF-16. I think the detected encoding should be set on EXCHANGE for the next steps by Camel.

Comment: I'm going to create a bug report for it, it needs to be fixed in several places...

Comment: hmmm there is a comment: `// woodstox's getLocation().etCharOffset() does not return the offset correctly for InputStream, so use Reader instead.
` which says that InputStream does not work?